# Не работает bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Какие примеры не использовала бы, колонки вместо того чтобы выстраиваться, например, вот так http://pro-cod.ru/uroki-bootstrap-3-0-dlya-nachinayushhix-tretij-urok.html, выстраиваются друг под другом. Я не знаю в чем трабл, на просторах интернета не могу найти ответ.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <h3>This is Photoshop's version</h3>
      This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh
</div>
```

Я пробовала и `md` и `lg` и `xs` и `sm`, все они у меня работают почему-то одинаково.

Answer (score 1):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

чтобы все в один ряд- надо все поместить в класс row.